# Gimp misses libraries after installing a compiled version and removing the package

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, gimp

I was trying to remove the older Gimp version in order to install the latest version on my Ubuntu 14.04, I've compiled and installed it. When I start gimp, it says that it was installed in the same directory(/usr/lib) and conflicts with the older one. I removed the package using both

```
apt-get purge gimp*
```

and

```
apt-get autoremove
```

If I do:

```
dpkg -l gimp
```

it says that it isn't installed, but if I type gimp in the terminal, the following message appears:

```
gimp: symbol lookup error:
gimp: undefined symbol:
gimp: symbol lookup error:
gimp: undefined symbol: g_type_check_instance_is_fundamentally_a
```

How can I remove it in order to do a fresh installation?

Comment: Did you check what actually is being executed after typing `gimp` with something like `which gimp`?

Comment: Where did you install your compiled copy: `/usr`, `/usr/local`, somewhere else? Run `ldd /usr/local/bin/gimp` (or whatever) to see which libraries it's pulling. There's a library version mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky the package has an uninstall target, so in the source directory where you compiled it run `sudo make uninstall`.  Otherwise you just have to manually delete the files it put in /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using `which gimp` to check where the binary lies as one user suggested, but if you don't know where it was originally installed, that might not be helpful.

My suggestion is run `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install gimp*` to overwrite the current installation files, then run `apt-get purge gimp*` and try again.

If this again causes a problem, depending on the reason for a clean install, you may just want to run `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install gimp*` then `apt-get remove gimp*` and manually delete config files which are causing problems, then `apt-get install gimp*` etc...

Good luck debugging!